# Interpreting Relationship Between Driver Names Output By lshw vs ubuntu-drivers list

Tags: configuration, gpu-driver

`apt list --installed | egrep -i 'nvidia|nouveau'` tells me that the only video driver I have installed is `nvidia-340`.

Executing `ubuntu-drivers list` I get:

```
nvidia-340
intel-microcode
nvidia-304
```

Executing `lshw -c video` I get:

```
configuration: driver=nvidia
```

Things get even more confusing when I look in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I see:

```
(EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

When I try `X -configure` to see if X can come up with anything related to nvidia, let alone nvidia-340 (which is the driver I need), nothing comes up -- not even `nouveau`.

Finally, `$ lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'` outputs:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 420] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 420]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 420] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 420]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_340
```

Comment: And what does `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'` say?

Comment: I've appended the output of  `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'` to the question.

Comment: The `lspci` output should be telling you the truth, meaning that `nvidia-340` is the used kernel module for driving the graphics card. I don't know what `ubuntu-drivers` is supposed to show, maybe all drivers it thinks could fit, or all that were ever installed? No idea, I get weird output from it as well. Not sure about the X stuff either, unfortunately, but `lspci -k` relaibly tells you the used kernel modules, so that's the real thing.

Comment: So I take it my confusion is between the terms "driver" and "module"?  In other words, when people talk about the "nouveau driver" they really should be saying "nouveau module" or, if they want to be redundantly verbose to be absolutely clear: "noveau module of the nvidia driver"?

Comment: I think you should read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47208/103151 and maybe https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127729/103151 for more information about drivers vs. kernel modules.

Comment: Perhaps I should but that doesn't answer my question about the proper usage of the terms.